# Dropzone inserting the same number of values as the same number of files when sending array inputs to backend

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dropzone

I have a simple dropbox that uploads files manually when a button is clicked:

```
var dropzone = $("#dropzone-form").dropzone({
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        paramName: "fotos",
        url: url,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        init: function(){
            var dropzone_object = this;



            $('#btn-guardar').on('click', function(e){
                if(checkForm()){
                    if(dropzone_object.files.length > 0){
                        dropzone_object.processQueue();
                    }else{
                      sendWithoutFiles();
                    }

                }
            });


        },
        sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {

            var formValues = $('#form-productos').serializeArray();
            $.each(formValues, function(i, obj){
               formData.append(obj.name, obj.value);
            });


        },
        success: function(file, response){

        },
        error: function(file, errorMessage, xhr){

        }
    });
```

But I'm having problems when I upload more than one file because I have array inputs inside my form with id `form-productos` such as this:

```
<input name="emails[]">
```

or

```
<select name="colors[]"></select>
```

So, for each file that the dropzone queue has, it appends the input again, the inputs that are NOT array inputs have no problem because the value just gets overwritten again, so let's suppose that I have the following inputs (NOTE THE VALUES):

```
<input name="emails[]" value="email1">
<input name="emails[]" value="email2">
```

And also, let's suppose that I have 2 files in the queue, when I press the button and the data is being sent to PHP, I get the following when I print "`$request->emails`":

```
array(
   'email1',
   'email2', //After this, since I uploaded two files, I get the same values again:
   'email1',
   'email2'  
)
```

Reading the dropzone [documentation](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list) clearly states that this is the correct behaviour:

> sending: Called just before each file is sent. Gets the xhr object and
>   the formData objects as second and third parameters, so you can modify
>   them (for example to add a CSRF token) or add additional data.

So, the problem is on my side, what can I do to prevent this when appending to `formData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue easily replacing the `send` event with `sendingmultiple`, this event should be used in most cases when the `uploadMultiple` option is set to `true`:

```
sendingmultiple: function(files, xhr, formData) {

            var formValues = $('#form-productos').serializeArray();
            $.each(formValues, function(i, obj){
               formData.append(obj.name, obj.value);
            });


        },
```

The difference is that this event receives a file array as first parameter, in this way, the process inside the event is only done once.